# Seeking software for visualization and sketch on yard from photos

Tags: planning, gis

I'm asking for software recommendation to use for my process. I'd like to digitize my yard using photogrammetry and then sketch some planned buildings on it, make a visualization, measure distances and so on.

I used AgiSoft Photoscan to digitize my photos (although, I was not very happy with automated process, I had to add many points but that may be because of my crappy photos) so I'd like to find alternative. I was thinking about exporting data to some common 3D format (covered with textures) and then using it in a software like Google Sketch-up.

Which software(s) would be good for this process? Of course I prefer free software but I'm willing to pay for a good software. I use Ubuntu linux but I have Windows machine available too. I'm a fan of GIS so no problem with using some not so much user-friendly software :) I know how to use QGis.

I have moved by question here from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245902/seeking-software-for-visualization-and-sketch-on-yard-from-photos